# Mercurial Queues - export a patch

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have a mercurial queue patch on my local machine that I need to share with a coworker that I'd prefer not to commit to an upstream repository. Is there a simple way that I can package that patch and share it with him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mq stores the patches in the `.hg\patches\` folder as files without an extension.

You can copy or email those files and use `hg qimport FILE` on the other end to bring them into the patch queue on the other repository. Note that if you copy it directly to the target `.hg\patches\` folder, you'll need to use the `--existing` switch so `hg` knows to not create the file.

The `.hg/patches` folder, by the way, can be a repository in itself to track changes in the patch queue itself. You can init it with `hg init --mq` and commit the current patches by `hg com --mq`.

Answer (score 0):

- If both sides have MQ enabled, you can use for pull|push --mq option
- You can use MQCollab extension
- You can just copy needed mq-patch from patch-directory (default: `.hg/patches) and transfer it using any way: patch is ordinary diff, which can be applied to "foreign" files in repository even without MQ

Comment: Could you spell out how to use pull|push --mq?

Comment: I'll add myself that an easy way to make a changeset from the patch (3rd option) is `hg import <patch>`.  (I messed around with the unix `patch < <patch>` at first, which is more awkward.)  As mentioned, this doesn't require mq on the destination.